# how to group by ID and if Type is wo then get the value from case# and copy that value to wo Case# column for all the same Id in SSME

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write the SQL query to get the result.

Table A looks like below.

| ID | Type | Case# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | wo | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 12 |
| 101 | tsk | 13 |
| 101 | tsk | 14 |
| 101 | tsk | 15 |
| 642 | wo | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 34 |
| 642 | tsk | 35 |
| 642 | tsk | 36 |
| 642 | tsk | 37 |

Expecting the result

| ID | Type | Case# | wo Case# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | wo | 23 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 12 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 13 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 14 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 15 | 23 |
| 642 | wo | 500 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 34 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 35 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 36 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 37 | 500 |

I am not sure how to do this

```sql
Select * from TableA
```

Comment: Why doesn't the 101, wo row get any wo Case# value, when the 642, wo row gets?

Comment: Take the time to *explain* the problem. Don't just dump some tables into your post, along with a (SQL) statement that doesn't make an attempt.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one Type = 'wo' row with the same ID?

Comment: there will be no more types other than wo and tsk. Also, there should be the value of wo in 101. I just edit that table here.

Comment: Thom A, if I knew how to attempt the query I won't be asking on this channel the solution.

Comment: `coalesce(max(case when type = 'wo' then casenum end) over (partition by id), casenum)` You don't have examples of non-wo groups though so possibly the coalesce is unnecessary.

Comment: So why haven't you *explained* the problem, @MGoyal ? If you don't understand your requirements, how can we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *window function* and *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT *,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'wo' THEN [Case#] END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS [wo Case#]
FROM TableA
```

Results:

| ID | Type | Case# | wo Case# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | wo | 23 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 12 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 13 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 14 | 23 |
| 101 | tsk | 15 | 23 |
| 642 | wo | 500 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 34 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 35 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 36 | 500 |
| 642 | tsk | 37 | 500 |
| 777 | wo | 701 | 702 |
| 777 | wo | 702 | 702 |
| 777 | tsk | 703 | 702 |
| 777 | tsk | 704 | 702 |
| 999 | tsk | 91 | *null* |
| 999 | tsk | 92 | *null* |

The `OVER(PARTITION BY ID)` part allows the `MAX()` to extend its scope to all rows having the same ID value. The `CASE...END` exclude all values except the one we are interested in.

If there is a chance you might have more than one Type = 'wo' row for a given ID, you will need to consider which value should be used and perhaps modify the window function with an `ORDER BY` within the `OVER()` clause.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rjx7cHAG) for a working example with a few extra test data rows.